# Can Any Square Matrix be Expressed as a Matrix Exponential of Some Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can *any* square matrix, $\hat{M}$, be written as $\hat{M} = e^{i\hat{O}}$, for some square matrix $\hat{O}$?  For instance, can $\hat{M} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & 0 &0 &0 \\0& 0 &0 &0\\0& 0 &0 &0\\0& 0 &0 &b \end{bmatrix}$? If not, what are the restrictions on $\hat{M}$, in order for the above to be possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Try the square matrix $[0]$ . This is obviously not the exponential of anything. More generally, there may be some theorem that the determinant of a matrix exponential is never zero. If that's the case, then any singular matrix is not an exponential. I'll look it up.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, $M$ is exponential of something if and only if $M$ is invertible. Hint:  pick a basis where $M$ is in Jordan normal form and look at condition where a Jordan block can be rewritten as an exponential.

Comment: This is called a matrix logarithm. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix

Comment: $I = \exp(O) = \exp(-A+A) = \exp(-A)\exp(A)$ , because $(-A)$ commutes with $A$ . It follows that $\exp(-A) = \exp(A)^{-1}$ . So any exponential is invertible (non-singular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Matrices of the form $e^A$ are always invertible (with inverse $e^{-A}$).